# how to pass an arraylist of books between activities

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an arraylist of type Book. How can I pass the array list to another activity and read from that list in the other activity? Here's what I have so far.

```
   txtViewAll.setOnClickListener {
                Intent(context, BookActivity::class.java).apply {
                    putExtra("list", list[layoutPosition].list)
                    context.startActivity(this)
                }
            }
```

// to read

```
val bookList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("list") as ArrayList<Book>
            for (book in bookList) {
                list.add(Book(book.id, book.title, book.image, book.subtitle, null, null, 0, 0));
            }
```

Here's each Book

```
data class Book(val id: String, val title: String, var image: String, var subtitle: String, var author: String?, var desc: String?, var uploadDate: Long,  var starCount: Long)
```

Comment: Implement your Book class as Parcelable & use bundle.putParcelableArrayList & in 2nd activity getParcelableArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`putParcelableArrayListExtra`**  & **`getParcelableArrayListExtra`**  .

Set this way

```
Intent(context, BookActivity::class.java).apply {
putParcelableArrayListExtra("list", list[layoutPosition].list)
context.startActivity(this)
```

Get this way

```
val bookList = this.intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Parcelable>("list") as ArrayList<Book>
```

You should use **Parcelable**

- Use **@Parcelize** annotation on top of your Model / Data class

Example

```
@Parcelize
data class Book
```

> Parcelable is an Android only interface which is used to serialize
>   class so its properties can be transferred from one activity to
>   another.

Comment: putParcelableArrayListExtra("list", list[layoutPosition].list) tells me that the second argument is of the wrong type

Comment: @LouisaScheinost seems like you should pass `list[layoutPosition]` instead of `list[layoutPosition].list`

Comment: I think this is bad solution, so many time i see app crash when list too large. You can create an variable in MainApplication class, it's better or save it in some database.

Comment: It is something to consider: TransactionTooLargeException. The limitation is different on different versions of Android, but you can probably consider it to be 1MB as a baseline. But for a large amount of variable data I would tend to reopen it from the DB in the new Activity. Having said that, the answer above is really educational in terms of what is being attempted.